# Using of the switch operator

Tags: php, syntax

Is it legitimate to use the switch operator in such way, if I want to print the first not empty var in order a,b,c. 
The only problem i see is result in case when some conditions will be true.
I've tested it on 5.6 and 7 versions of php
But will it not be depend on the version of php?

```
$a = '';
$b = '';
$c = 'c';

switch (true) {
  case (!empty($a)) :
    echo $a;
    break;
  case (!empty($b)) :
    echo $b;
    break;
  default:
    echo $c;
};
```

Comment: you may use http://3v4l.org to test your code across multiple versions

Comment: It isn't good.... what ae you actually trying to do here? I can't tell from the code you've posted, which means it isn't very good

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to print the first not empty var in order a,b,c. It work on php5.6 :)

Comment: The only problem i see is result in case when some conditions will be true

Comment: legitimate but clearly bad coding style in any book... you're clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: I know this mantra :). I would like to understand why

Comment: Jesus. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the values in an array; filter to remove empty; then display the first element.... will you always have at least one non-empty value, or is it possible for them all to be empty?

Comment: The last is always not empty. i thought about that or about creating function with variable argument lists. In both cases there are temporary variables. In this approach existing ones used

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't think  that `echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;` is better :)

Comment: @splash58 - nested ternaries is an even worse idea than switch statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not relying on any undocumented behaviour here, and it is unlikely this will change in any future version of PHP.

The trick of using `switch(true)` is sometimes discussed as though it was an extra operator, but it's actually just a consequence of how switch statements work - each `case` condition is compared with the value in the `switch` with `==`, so you're effectively checking `$condition == true` each time.

Your code:

```
switch (true) {
  case (!empty($a)) :
    echo $a;
  break;
  case (!empty($b)) :
    echo $b;
  break;
  default:
    echo $c;
}
```

It's equivalent to:

```
  if (true == !empty($a))  {
    echo $a;
    goto end;
  }
  if (true == !empty($b)) {
    echo $b;
    goto end;
  }
  // fallback
  echo $c;
  // goto target
  end:
```

Since you're not using any fall through, we can rewrite the `goto` parts with `else`and `elseif`:

```
  if (true == !empty($a))  {
    echo $a;
  }
  elseif (true == !empty($b)) {
    echo $b;
  }
  else {
    echo $c;
  }
```

And of course the `true ==` is redundant as well:

```
  if (!empty($a))  {
    echo $a;
  }
  elseif (!empty($b)) {
    echo $b;
  }
  else {
    echo $c;
  }
```

As long as every `case` has a corresponding `break`, these different pieces of code are guaranteed to be identical based on the fundamental definition of a switch statement. The last is by far the most common, and thus easiest for other people to read your code.

The big difference with `switch` is that you can "fall through" and combine cases in different ways. If you need to do this, then the `switch (true)` form may be useful. If you don't need it, you should probably avoid the risk of *accidentally* falling through by using a normal if-elseif chain.

Comment: Thank you, IMSoP ! The last paragraph of your answer is what I wanted to hear

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '';
$b = '';
$c = 'c';

if(!empty($a)){
    echo $a;
}elseif (!empty($b)){
    echo $b;
}else{
    echo $c;
}
```

`elseif` is the best and general Way!

Comment: The question is not about how to write the code (I know not less that 3 ways). It's about switch's behavior